# Вызов ассемблерного кода из кода на C++

Tags: ассемблер, c++, linux

И снова здравствуйте, уважаемые гуру! Подскажите, пожалуйста, как вызвать из проекта, написанного на C++, программу на ассемблере, находящуюся в отдельном файле. Linux, AT&T синтаксис ассемблера, среда разработки NetBeans 7.1.

Comment: Зависит от соглашений о связях (передача параметров, возврат), которых придерживается вызываемая программа.

Comment: Описать её как внешнюю (`extern "C"`), добавить при линковке (я не знаю netbeans) и вперёд.

Comment: Где мне описывать ее как внешнюю? В заголовочном файле проекта описал, обратиться не могу!

Comment: А "не могу" как перевести на русский язык? Не хватает сил нажать Enter? Или всё-таки будет более конкретное описание ситуации?

Comment: В папку проекта добавил файл cp.S, в файле asm.h добавил код

    extern "C++"{ int foo(char a, char b); }

В файле asm.cpp функцию foo(char a, char b) вызвать не получается. Если не ошибаюсь в intel асме пишется ключевое слово public, мне нужно что-нибудь прописывать в ассемблеровсом файле?

Comment: Ещё. Там есть разные типы передачи параметров: cdecl, fastcall, stdcall, regparm. См. доки.

Comment: Понял, буду смотреть

Comment: "типы передачи параметров" еще называют "конвенциями вызовов"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ну во-первых почему `extern "C++"`? Я не знаю, что там у вас в cp.S, но c++ делает с именами некоторые фокусы (name mangling кажется), добавляя информацию о типах. Так что `extern "C"` скорее всего. Насчёт public -- не знаю, gcc вставил бы .global foo Надо либо читать документацию, либо делать, как он. cp.S -- лучше cp.s.

```
    extern "C" {extern int foo(char a, char b); } // забыл это отметить

    as -o foo.o cp.S
    g++ asm.cpp foo.o
```

Comment: @alexlz, спасибо